# SQL Server Database Query with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, excel

I need to get some data from a Microsoft SQL Server database at work. When I have the data I need, I need to make an Excel spreadsheet that can be saved locally on my computer.

I found [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) which seems to do the job on the Excel part, but what about getting the data from the Database?

I can't seem to find anything that's recent. Only old tutorials.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to use Excel to connect directly to SQL server (data tab; From other sources -> From SQL Server)

Comment: I didn't say I was gonna connect directly to the SQL with Excel.

Comment: I would query the database and then create a *CSV* file

Comment: It needs to be Excel. There is no alternative to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this way to Fetch the Records :

```
<?php
$hostname = "192.168.3.50";
$username = "sa";
$password = "123456";
$dbName = "yourdb";

MSSQL_CONNECT($hostname,$username,$password) or DIE("DATABASE FAILED TO RESPOND.");
mssql_select_db($dbName) or DIE("Database unavailable");

$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.table";

$result = mssql_query( $query );

for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_rows( $result ); ++$i)
     {
         $line = mssql_fetch_row($result);
         print( "$line[0] - $line[1]\n");
     }
?>
```

This will fetch each rows from the Data Retrieve and Print on the Page. Use your Required format into that. I mean, Use html Table to show the data in well format.

Comment: I am coming from a Java/C# background is it a 2D array with [row][column] ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to get an data from Database.

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = '192.168.3.50';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'sa');
if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
else{
    echo "connected ";


  mssql_select_db('Matrix') or die("Wrong DATAbase");

   //mssql_query("SELECT Seq_no from dbo.Trans_R WHERE Seq_no = 000001",$link) or         die("cannot execute the query");

  $query = mssql_query("SELECT Tr_Date,Tr_Time,Tr_Data from Matrix.dbo.Trans_R");

$f = mssql_fetch_array($query);

    echo $f['Tr_Date'];

}
?>
```

Can i know why Negative Vote??

He asked me to :

> " but what about getting the data from the Database?"

Comment: So, how would I shift through the data I get so I only extract the right data?

Comment: Now you can Add Criteria.
Use Where Clause to Filter the Right data you want. 
To use Where Clause Checkout this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx

Comment: **And, Can you please Specify your tables and Your requirements? So, that, we could help you easily?**

Comment: The SQL Statement is not important. I will figure that out. It's really just how to fetch the data, and how to navigate the array or collection I get from executing the query.

Comment: So, What this mean :

 **So, how would I shift through the data I get so I only extract the right data?**. Didnt you mean to filter record you want?

Comment: Oh oh i misunderstood...okey i'll be writing

Comment: My initial question is how to extract data from an MSSQL Database with PHP because I couldn't find any information on that. Then my question to you is how I shift through the data I get