# Create PHP Drop Down List from SQL Express DB

Tags: php, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I have created an HTML front-end. There is information in a locally stored database that I want to display in a drop down menu. In one menu, I would also like to add/enter information to be stored in the db.

Never used PHP before, but I know this is the route I need to take in order to accomplish my goal. Any tips on how to do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: This site is about getting help with specific programming questions. It is not designed to be a please provide with a working example kind of place. There are LOTS of example of how to do this all over the internet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342000/sql-server-database-query-with-php

This may be of some use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670002/php-get-dropdown-value-and-text).

Should have answer you need. The person asking the question also used database to populate a drop down list.

Here's a code example (originally from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-create-combo-box-in-php/7105)):

```
$server = 'servername';
$database = 'database_name';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM your_cable")     or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
{
echo '<select name="drop_2" id="drop_2">
      <option value=" " selected="selected">Choose one</option>';
       while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
        {
          echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['column_name'].'">'.$drop_2['column_name'].'</option>';
        }
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I was making a point that you can retrieve from the database and then populate the list.

Comment: Or are you asking more of 'how to retrieve from the database'?

Comment: Check this [site](https://www.idtech.com/blog/populating-a-combo-box-in-php-dynamically-from-mysql/) then.

Comment: No.
You'll need to change mysql_connect and mysql_select_db to mssql_connect, etc.
Check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)
Should be easy to do! Good luck.

Comment: So you copied and pasted an answer from a 6 year old [post on another site](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-create-combo-box-in-php/7105/2) that isn't even using the same type of database. This is not helpful. The question is too broad to be useful, and answering it just clutters the site up.