# In XAMPP 7.1.12 I am not getting any output

Tags: php, sql-server, php-7

I wrote a function to fetch the user_status from SQL Server but its seems everything is correct but still I am not getting any output.

My connection with SQL Server is established. And my function is as follows:

```
function fetchuserStatus($username,$password) {
    include("db-settings.php");   
    if ($conn) {
        $sql = "SELECT User_status from _yb_all_users_tbl where User_name = ? AND Password = ?";
        $parameters = array($username,$password);
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $parameters);
        if( $stmt === false ) {
          die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
         }
        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) === true) {
            sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);  
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
    } else {
        echo "Connection is not established";
    }
}
echo fetchuserStatus($username,$password);
```

And my db-settings.php file is:

```
$serverName = ".";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "yaadbook",
    "UID" => "sa",
    "PWD" => "shiftu"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);
if($conn) {
} else {
    echo "Connection Failure";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}
```

I am using PHP version 7.1.12. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: use my sqlsrv_errors() to see any errors.after you execute query

Comment: @RohitS yes i have used. But still i am not getting any errors. I had edit the code.Please check. I am new with SQL SERVER database

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal while adding question please add relevant tags also

Comment: @kunal Can you please rewrite the code. I didn't get exactly what you saying. Thanks

Comment: I am not too much familiar with sql server .Even Hope this link helps you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456078/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-php7-what-am-i-missing

Comment: @kunal The following link used PDO. which i am not aware of.

Comment: @NikitaAgrawal try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342000/sql-server-database-query-with-php

Comment: you need to google out more

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting output because I need to use `sqlsrv_execute()`  after `sqlsrv_prepare()`.

Here is my complete code:

```
function fetchuserStatus($username,$password){ 
  include("db-settings.php");   
  $sql = "SELECT * from _yb_all_users_tbl where User_name = ? AND Password = ?";
  $parameters = array($username,$password);
  $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $parameters);
  sqlsrv_execute($stmt); 
  if(!$stmt) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     return $row;
  }
  sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
  sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
```